# Mongoose / NodeJS - String from db is retrieved but considered as not defined

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here's my problem now:

I query a `findOne` and populate on my DB in order to retrieve an array of string to use in my `.EJS` but the log says that the value is not defined but its give the value name : "*stringName* is not defined"

I must have missed something..

This is the User schema :

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {  type: String, required: true, index: {  
    unique: true } },
    email: {  type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true } },
    password: {  type: String, required: true },
    tables: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Table' }],
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    uuid: String,                
});
```

This is the Table schema :

```
var TableSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    logos: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Logo'}],
});
```

This is where I do the query and send the document to the .ejs page:

```
app.get('/dashboard/:uuid', function(req, res){
    if (req.user && userId != "")
    {
        var query = User.findOne({username:    req.user.username}).populate('tables').select('tables');

        query.exec(function (err, tables){
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log (tables.tables[0].name); // Return the right string name
            res.render('./pages/dashboard.ejs', {username: req.user.username, tables: tables.tables});
        });
    }
    else
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

And this is the script in ejs that is supposed to render the table names in my page:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
         <% for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {%>
         var newTab = "<a href=\"/work\"><div class=\"square\" style=\"display: inline-block\"><span style=\"margin-top: 50%; text-align: center\">" + <%=tables[i].name%> + "</span></div></a>";
         $(newTab).appendTo('.jumbotron');
         <%}%>

    });
</script>
```

If you guys could enlighten up a bit my way that would be so great !

Comment: In `app.get` route, you're using `userId` but I don't see where this is defined?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer @timothyclifford, userId is defined elsewhere by using PassportJS, everything works well over there

Comment: Where is your log statement being generated?

Comment: in chrome browser : " Uncaught ReferenceError: *stringName* is not defined "
(stringName = what's in tables[0].name)

Comment: If you do a `console.log` of `tables` before your `for` loop, what is it being set to? Sounds like it's null...

Comment: if I do : <%console.log(tables);%>
I get : 
[{"_id":"575a7ae98e519a2d10791dbb","name":"hey","__v":0,"logos":[]},{"_id":"575a7f714082255310b02d22","name":"pop","__v":0,"logos":[]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this implementation, this is how i would query schema, in firs example we reuse `req.user` (good), in second we make 2 database calls (bad). In your example you make 1 database call but not populating `Logo` field of table schema (bad).

```
app.get('/dashboard/:uuid', function(req, res){
    // first example
    // no need to query users, you already have tables field
    if (!req.user) // what is userId, why you check it
        // add `err` checks
        return res.redirect('/');

    TableSchema
        .find({ _id: { $in: req.user.tables } })
        .populate('logos', 'url'); // Logo schema fields
        .exec(function(err, result_tables){
           res.render('./pages/dashboard.ejs', {username: req.user.username, tables: result_tables});
    });

    // or second example
    // if you still for some reason cannot use req.user.tables field
    // but strongly recommend to use first one
    User.findById(req.user._id, 'tables') 
        .exec(function (err, user_tables){
            // add `err` checks
            TableSchema.populate(user_tables, { path: 'logos', model: 'Logo' }, function (err, result_tables){
                // add `err` checks
                res.render('./pages/dashboard.ejs', {username: req.user.username, tables: result_tables});
            });
    });
});
```

As per your comment

> in chrome browser : " Uncaught ReferenceError: stringName is not defined " (stringName = what's in tables[0].name)

Try to use forEach operator

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
         <% tables.forEach(function(table){ %>
             var newTab = "<a ommited><%= table.name %></a>"; //notice: no `"`
             $(newTab).appendTo('.jumbotron');
         <% }) %>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey !
I tried your first example and I have the same result as with my way :-/

With the forEach: table.name throw the error " unexpected string " ...

Comment: @Naguib try again with `"<a ommited><%= table.name %></a>"; //notice: no "`